# use string to define function argument key/name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know theres other ways to work around this but I'm more just curious if it's possible. Can you use a string to define the key for a function input, like so?

```
#example function
def printword(word):
    print(word)

#normal use
printword(word='hello') #would print 'hello'

#trying to use dynamic function key
inp='word'
printword(eval(inp)='hello') #error
```

Comment: Presumably you don't want to use a dict? `kwargs = {"word": "hello"}` then `printword(**kwargs)`

Comment: `eval(f"printword({inp}='hello')")` also works.

Comment: thanks! Both of those work excellently